# no puedo hacer click en mi sidebar que tengo en mis widgets y no puedo alinear los elementos de la pagina como lo puedo solucionar?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

tardes o noches tengo el siguiente problema en wordpress con el single page de productos de woocommerce tengo un sidebar que lo agrego con un hook , pero no encuentro alguno en especifico que me pueda poner el sidebar del lado izquiero sin que me desacomode los demas elementos , y otro de mis problemas es que no puedo hacer click al sidebar por que? muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta nota: el sidebar lo tengo en mis widgets. dejo una imagen para que puedan observar como tengo mi pagina busco que me acomode primero el sidebar del lado izquierdo, despues la imagen del producto y por ultimo su descripcion con su precio y boton de agregar al carrito.

```
function funcion_agregar_Sidebar(){
dynamic_sidebar('Barra lateral');
```

}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','funcion_agregar_Sidebar');

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: algo que olvide mencionar, esa funcion es un snippet

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Titulo = Idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = Detalles. 2. Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.